# programmatically erase android browser cache, history, etc. with root

Tags: android, location, browser-cache

I have an android tablet that is locked down (users will only be able to use standard issue android browser), so all the temporary internet stuff should be in the same place.

Assuming I am able to `root the device` sometime here soon, I would like to be able to wipe out (1) cookies,(2) temp internet files,(3) history,(4) form data,(5) location access info,(6) passwords, (7) cache.

I think I can knock out most of these by erasing:

```
/data/data/com.android.browser/cache
```

The cookies appear to be in a database. I'm not sure if I can just `delete it`

```
/data/data/com.android.browser/databases/webview.db
```

And then I think I can just delete these files to `erase` location information:

```
/data/data/com.google.android.location/files/wifi

/data/data/com.google.android.location/files/cell
```

Will that take care of everything?

What am I leaving out?

Is it safe to just `erase that database`? Does anyone know?

Answer (score 0):

how about something as simple as

```
adb shell pm clear com.android.browser
```

from command line ?

Answer (score 0):

This API is deprecated in Android Marshmallow. If you build using API 23 it wont work any more.

You can delete them @micahhoover,
You can delete complete com.android.browser sub directories, every time you relaunch browser, all the sub folders gets created.

To delete android browser History(Default)

in your Activity.java file add the follwing code

```
Browser.clearHistory(getContentResolver());
```

In your manifest add

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.browser.permission.WRITE_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.browser.permission.READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS"/>
```

Comment: this is working @Chethan Shetty how can i delete google play store search history ?

Comment: @Erum glad to know clear browser history and bookmark is working for you. But I'm not sure about how to clear Play store search cache.

Comment: cannot resolve the method clearHistory
(android.content.contentresolver)

Comment: This feature is removed in Android marshmallow devices. If you build your app in 23 or above it won't get.