# Delete Android Default Browser History

Tags: android

I'm trying to develop an android application that could erase default browser's search history without rooting, but I'm stuck. Here is my source code

```
File file = new File("data/data/com.android.browser/databases/browser.db");

            try {

                String content = "";



                if(!file.exists()) {
                    file.createNewFile();
                }

                FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
                bw.write(content);
                bw.close();

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "History Deleted From Default Browser", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                System.out.println("Done");

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

As i know browser's history will be stored in "browser.db" file, i can able to clear history only if I change the permission of browser.db file in command prompt through adb shell like "chmod 777 data/data/com.android.browser/databases/browser.db"
But i need to do it every time, i want to do this inside my application source code, I also tried Runtime.exec() methods to execute adb shell, actually History Eraser app can erase the history of default browser without root permission, Can any one please help me out in solving this mystery. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: you are tyring to break the sandbox - that won't work!  checkhttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/7235741/programmatically-erase-android-browser-cache-history-etc-with-root?rq=1

Comment: But there are lots of history cleaner apps like History Eraser for example can erase without rooting @LordT. If they can do it there has to be some way right ?

Comment: from JNI, you can run `system()` call, but not sure that works

Comment: @SIGSEGV even if we run we might need root acces isn't it ?End user afraid of rooting their mobiles, so I'm targetting the app to work in all kind of environment, But I'm stuck here. Any way thanks for your time. SIGSEGV

Comment: @ChethanShetty No, if you are able to run `adb shell pm clear com.android.browser ` without rooting then `system()` call from jni will work i hope.

Comment: @SIGSEGV I tried to execute "adb shell pm clear com.android.browser" but I got "Error: unknown command clear"

Comment: tried `adb shell rm data/data/com.android.browser/databases/browser.db` ?

Comment: @SIGSEGV Thanks, I'm able to delete browser.db file, buit problem is history is not getting deleted. But previousle history was erasing.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Browser.html#clearHistory(android.content.ContentResolver) ?

Comment: public static final void clearHistory (ContentResolver cr) But what to pass as parameter value for ContentResolver @shoe rat

Comment: Try what shoe rat has said - that seems to be the correct way to solve it!

Comment: @LordT I tried, but it won't work, You need to pass ContentResolver reference variable to get database connection, ContentResolver rference variable only get database vvalue if its been initalised by OS, so we can't use clearHistory(cr) method.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add the following permissions to `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.browser.permission.WRITE_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.browser.permission.READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS"/>
```

Then when you want to clear the history use:

```
Browser.clearHistory(getContentResolver());
```

Comment: cannot resolve the method clearHistory
(android.content.contentresolver)

Comment: These permissions are removed in API 23 or above. So if you are targeting 23 or above this make some error.